# Getting error Geocoder failed while fetching current location using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am getting the following error while trying to fetch current location using Google Maps API.

Error:

```
Geocoder failed
```

I am providing my code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

function getDefaultLocation(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var geocoder='';
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
                }
                function successFunction(position) {
                   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                   var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                   codeLatLng(lat, lng)
                }
                function errorFunction(){
                   console.log("Geocoder failed");
                }
                function codeLatLng(lat, lng){
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                        if (results[1]) {
                          var indice=0;
                            for (var j=0; j<results.length; j++){
                              if (results[j].types[0]=='locality'){
                                indice=j;
                                break;
                              }
                              for (var i=0; i<results[j].address_components.length; i++){
                                if (results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "locality") {
                                  city = results[j].address_components[i];
                                }
                                if(results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1"){
                                  region = results[j].address_components[i];
                                }
                                if (results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "country"){
                                  country = results[j].address_components[i];
                                }
                                if(results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "route"){
                                  locality=results[j].address_components[i];
                                }
                              }
                            }
                           // console.log('final result',city.long_name,region.long_name,country.long_name,locality.long_name);
        var city=city.long_name;
         var country=country.long_name;
        var locality=locality.long_name;

                                    document.getElementById('bindCon').innerHTML=country;                           document.getElementById('bindCit').innerHTML=city;                      document.getElementById('bindloc').innerHTML=locality;
 }else{
    console.log("No results found");
 }
                        }else{
                          console.log("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
            })
         }
    },5000);
}
```

The above code is working properly in `localhost` but while putting this into my testing site (`http://xxxx.com`) the above error is coming. Here I need to fetch all the required data.

Comment: it's actually working, did you allow the domain from getting your location?
https://jsfiddle.net/98s5xh1w/

Comment: @Roljhon : Its working for localhost fine but in chrome error is `1
message
"Only secure origins are allowed "` and for firefox error is `{ code: 2, message: "Unknown error acquiring position" }`.

Comment: for `https` its working fine but i have `http`.

Comment: ahhh, i see, well i think that's a limitation, localhost is I think treated as secure origin by google for testing purposes, there are workarounds I guess, see here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for testing I think, but for production, I think it requires your domain to be secure

Comment: But in Mozila its different error.

Comment: `https://` is required for geolocation to work in modern browsers.  The google maps API now **requires** an API key (and that key needs to have an associated billing account activated with a credit card). (also, the `sensor` parameter is no longer required)